# a question on delta systems

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

I have two questions relating to existence of a delta system of certain cardinality:

a) Show that for every family  $F = \{S_\alpha : \alpha<(2^{\aleph_0})^+\}$  of countable sets, $F$ includes a delta system of cardinality $(2^{\aleph_0})^+$.

b) Show that there exists a family $F = \{S_\alpha : \alpha<2^{\aleph_0}\}$ (each set still countable) such that there does not exist a delta system of cardinality $3$.

Apart from the definition of delta systems, I know the delta system lemma, but that's about it, and the lemma does not appear to directly help me here (although I probably need to figure out some way to use it). How can I approach these two problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ll write $\mathscr{F}$ for your $F$.

Suppose that if $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{F}$ is a $\Delta$-system then $|\mathscr{A}|\le 2^\omega$. I’ll construct families $\mathscr{F}_\xi$ for $\xi<\omega_1$ in such a way that $\mathscr{F}=\bigcup_{\xi<\omega_1}\mathscr{F}_\xi$, and $|\mathscr{F}_\xi|\le 2^\omega$ for each $\xi<\omega_1$; this implies that $|\mathscr{F}|\le\omega_1\cdot2^\omega=2^\omega$ and so proves the theorem.

Start by letting $\mathscr{F}_0$ be a maximal pairwise disjoint subfamily of $\mathscr{F}$. If $\eta<\omega_1$, and $\mathscr{F}_\xi$ has been defined for each $\xi<\eta$, let $\mathscr{F}_\eta'=\bigcup_{\xi<\eta}\mathscr{F}_\xi$, and let $F_\eta=\bigcup\mathscr{F}_\eta'$. For each countable $K\subseteq F_\eta$ let

$$\mathscr{F}_\eta(K)=\{S\in\mathscr{F}\setminus\mathscr{F}_\eta':S\cap F_\eta=K\}\;.$$

If there are $S_\alpha,S_\beta\in\mathscr{F}_\eta(K)$ such that $S_\alpha\cap S_\beta=K$, let $\mathscr{F}_\eta'(K)$ be a maximal $\Delta$-system in $\mathscr{F}_\eta(K)$ such that $\bigcap\mathscr{F}_\eta'(K)=K$; otherwise, let $\mathscr{F}_\eta'(K)$ be any maximal $\Delta$-system in $\mathscr{F}_\eta(K)$. Finally, set

$$\mathscr{F}_\eta=\bigcup\{\mathscr{F}_\eta'(K):K\subseteq F_\eta\text{ and }|K|\le\omega\}\;.$$

I leave it to you to check that if $|\mathscr{F}_\xi\le 2^\omega$ for each $\xi<\eta$, then $|\mathscr{F}_\eta|\le 2^\omega$ as well.

It only remains to show that $\bigcup_{\xi<\omega_1}\mathscr{F}_\xi=\mathscr{F}$, so suppose that $S\in\mathscr{F}\setminus\bigcup_{\xi<\omega_1}\mathscr{F}_\xi$.

- Now show that $S\cap(F_{\xi+1}\setminus F_\xi)\ne\varnothing$ for each $\xi<\omega_1$, and get a contradiction by concluding that $|S|>\omega$. HINT: For each $\xi<\omega_1$ you want to consider the set $K=S\cap F_\xi$.

(That last step isn’t entirely trivial, but I want to give you a chance to work on it on your own; if you get completely stuck, I can say more.)

For the second question let $\mathscr{F}={}^\omega\{0,1\}$, the set of functions from $\omega$ to $\{0,1\}$, viewed as subsets of $\omega\times\{0,1\}$.

---

**Added:** After writing the original answer, I realized that I know another proof that is perhaps a little easier. I’ll give you your choice of which you find easier to complete.

Let $\kappa$ be the ordinal (and cardinal) $(2^\omega)^+$; since $|\bigcup\mathscr{F}|=\kappa$, we may as well assume that $\bigcup\mathscr{F}\subseteq\kappa$. For each $\alpha<\omega_1$ let $\mathscr{F}_\alpha=\{S\in\mathscr{F}:S\text{ has order-type }\alpha\}$; clearly there is some $\alpha<\omega_1$ such that $|\mathscr{F}_\alpha|=\kappa$, so without loss of generality we may assume that each $S\in\mathscr{F}$ has order-type $\alpha$. For each $S\in\mathscr{F}$ let $S=\{\sigma_\xi^S:\xi<\alpha\}$ be an increasing enumeration of $S$.

For each $\eta<\kappa$ we have $|\eta|\le 2^\omega$, so $\eta$ has at most $2^\omega$ countable subsets, and $\bigcup\mathscr{F}$ must be unbounded in $\kappa$. There is therefore some $\eta<\alpha$ such that $\{\sigma_\eta^S:S\in\mathscr{F}\}$ is unbounded in $\kappa$. Let $\eta_0$ be the smallest such $\eta$, and let $$\beta_0=\sup\{\sigma_\xi^S+1:S\in\mathscr{F}\text{ and }\xi<\eta_0\}\;;$$ check that $\beta_0<\kappa$, and observe that $\sigma_\xi^S<\beta_0$ for all $S\in\mathscr{F}$ and $\xi<\eta_0$.

Recursively choose $S_\gamma\in\mathscr{F}$ for each $\gamma<\kappa$ in such a way that

$$\sigma_{\eta_0}^{S_\gamma}>\max\left\{\beta_0,\sup\left\{\sigma_{\xi}^{S_\delta}:\delta<\gamma\text{ and }\xi<\alpha\right\}\right\}\;.$$

In other words, each $\sigma_{\eta_0}^{S_\gamma}$ is larger than $\beta_0$ and larger than every element of $\bigcup_{\delta<\gamma}S_\delta$.

Now let $\mathscr{F}'=\{S_\gamma:\gamma<\kappa\}$.

- Show that $|\mathscr{F}'|=\kappa$.
- Show that if $\delta<\gamma<\kappa$, then $S_\delta\cap S_\gamma\subseteq\beta_0$.
- Use the previous observation to show that $\mathscr{F}'$ contains a $\Delta$-system $\mathscr{D}$ such that $|\mathscr{D}|=\kappa$ and $\bigcap\mathscr{D}\subseteq\beta_0$.

Comment: I guess this subject is much more difficult than I thought. I have trouble following even the first paragraph haha. "Suppose that if A⊆F is a Δ-system then |A|≤2ω. I’ll construct families Fξ for ξ<ω1 in such a way that F=⋃ξ<ω1Fξ, and |Fξ|≤2ω for each ξ<ω1; this implies that |F|≤ω1⋅2ω=2ω and so proves the theorem." If I understand correctly, what the paragraph says is: we will show that every delta system in this family cannot be at most continuum, because otherwise the family itself is at most continuum, but by the lemma there is a delta system, so it has to be correct size. Is that right?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: I’d phrase it a little differently: we will indeed show that if every $\Delta$-subsystem is too small, then the family must have been too small, but then we’ll simply take the contrapositive: if the family is big enough, then it must have a big enough $\Delta$-subsystem. (Here *too small* means of power at most the continuum, and *big enough* means *bigger than the continuum*.) You may find the alternative proof that I just added a little simpler. At any rate its difficulties are in different places!

Comment: Hey, I took a vacation and am now trying to make sense of this material. I've solved the second question using your suggestion, and am looking at your second solution of the first question. I think I've worked out the details (currently writing them down) except for the last thing, where it says "Use the previous observation...". How do we get from the intersections being contained in $\beta_0$ to a delta system where the intersections are all the same set?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: $\beta_0<\kappa$, so $|\beta_0|<\kappa$, i.e., $|\beta_0|\le 2^\omega$. Consider the sets $S_\gamma\cap\beta_0$. Each of them is countable; how many countable subsets of $\beta_0$ are there? How many sets $S_\gamma$ are there?

Comment: There are $2^\omega$ countable subsets, and $\kappa$ many $S_\gamma$'s, therefore there is a subset $R$ of $\beta_0$ such that for $\kappa$ many $S_\gamma$'s, $S_\gamma \cap \beta_0 = R$. This means these $S_\gamma$'s are a delta system of size $\kappa$ with root R! Hooray! Another thing: the reason $\beta_0<\kappa$, is that sup{σSξ+1:S∈F} is bounded for each ξ< η0, and there are countably many of those, so therefore $beta_0$ is bounded. Correct?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks sir. Although as I'm writing everything down I'm sure I will find new things I don't understand ;)

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat: You're welcome.